# What is the simplest way to add logging to a background worker in AppHarbor

Tags: appharbor

I have a console app that uses Quartz and sends out emails on a schedule. I want some basic logging so I can see if the app has started and configured (NHibernate) correctly, and also any stack traces from uncaught exceptions.

I could set up Log4net or similar to write log entries to a database table, or email them to me. But is there a simple way built into AppHarbor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [LogEntries](https://appharbor.com/applications/fluidcard/addons/logentries) Add on. Then install the le_log4net nuget package and enter your api key in the app.config. There is a Free subscription that should tell you what you need.

Comment: Sounds nice and easy (https://logentries.com/doc/appharbor/). Will try it out today. Thanks.